# In R, Performance Analytics package, chart.Drawdown, plot several drawdowns curves on the same plot

Tags: performanceanalytics, charts, drawdown

Dear Stack Exchange community,

Using Performance Analytics package, chart.Drawdown, I would like to plot several drawdowns curves on the same plot to be able to visually compare them.

I know how to plot one drawdown curve using:

> chart.Drawdown(R, geometric = TRUE, legend.loc = NULL, colorset = (1:12))

Is it possible to plot several curves? Can someone help me on that? Best. Joe.

Comment: A warm welcome to Quant.SE - see my answer below: http://quant.stackexchange.com/a/33654/12

Comment: TY! Loving it already!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No problem, just have a look at the following example from the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PerformanceAnalytics/PerformanceAnalytics.pdf) (p. 49):

```
data(edhec)
chart.Drawdown(edhec[ , c(1, 2)], 
     main = "Drawdown from Peak Equity Attained", 
     legend.loc = "bottomleft")
```

[image]